# Phoenix: using "conn" and "case" in a view

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have some client static jQuery code that I want to replace with server dynamic code that is used on every page of my website and depends on the page that I'm in (the route that was asked).
My existing jQuery code (in the template html.eex file) is:

```
    if (SOME CONDITION) {
        $(".page1.firstChild").css({"margin-top": "70px"});
        $(".page2.firstChild").css({"margin-top": "70px"});
        $(".page3.firstChild").css({"margin-top": "70px"});
        $(".page4.firstChild").css({"margin-top": "70px"});
    } else {
            $(".page1.firstChild").css({"margin-top": "0px"});
            $(".page2.firstChild").css({"margin-top": "0px"});
            $(".page3.firstChild").css({"margin-top": "0px"});
            $(".page4.firstChild").css({"margin-top": "0px"});
    }
```

So, I want to replace "`.page1`", "`.page2`",..."`.pageN`" with a variable that is placed in the template using `<% currentPage %>` and is defined in my layout_view so that it can be accessible on every page related with that layout. So I tried this:

```
defmodule myApp.LayoutView do
  use myApp.Web, :view

    def currentPage do
        case @conn.request_path do
            "/page1" -> "page1"
            "/page2" -> "page2"
            "/page3" -> "page3"
        end
    end
end
```

I'm getting this error:

```
undefined function: nil.request_path/0
```

What's the best way of doing this right? (I'm also not sure about the "case" code).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@conn` is available in your template as it is passed through `assigns`.

However you can't define a function and have it available. It needs to be passed as an argument to your function:

```
defmodule myApp.LayoutView do
  use myApp.Web, :view

  def current_page(conn) do
    case conn.request_path do
      "/page1" -> "page1"
      "/page2" -> "page2"
      "/page3" -> "page3"
    end
  end
end
```

You can call this from your template with:

```
current_page(@conn)
```

Please note in elixir, functions should be in `snake_case` and not `camelCase`.

Using `case` in the function is fine unless there is a clear mapping between your path and result. If you actually just want to remove the leading `"/"` then you could do:

```
iex(3)> String.slice("/page1", 1..-1)  
"page1"
```